# Youtube api doesn't return video entries when uri includes author parameter

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

I was doing a request to get videos from a youtube channel using youtube-api v2. Request example:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=UCTYHNSWYy4jCSCj1Q1Fq0ew&alt=json&v=2&orderby=published&start-index=1&max-results=6&fields=entry(title,media:group/yt:videoid,media:group/yt:duration),link
```

Where the author is a channel-id. That request was ran properly returning videos-entries infos as expected. For some reason the api call has returned empty entries (no videos).

I figured out some hypotheses like youtube-api quota exceeded or the feature has been dropped.  I looked at to youtube releases notes but no mentionation has been done to feature dropped.

Does it have some reason for this api call stopping to work or some place to debug it?

Comment: API V2 is deprecated, you need to use API V3

Comment: This is true, however there appears to be a problem and no v3 queries are returning results at the moment: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6598